# Where to place requirements.yml for Ansible and use it to resolve dependencies?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I am new to ansible and was exploring dependent roles. [documentation link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/galaxy.html)

What I did not come across the documentation was- where to place the `requirements.yml` file.

For instance, if my `site.yml` looks like this:

```
---
- name: prepare system
  hosts: all
  roles:
     - role1
```

And, lets say

- role1 depends on role2 and role3
- role2 depends on role4 and role5

Typically, ansible-galaxy  have the following structure:

```
└── test-role
    ├── defaults
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── files
    ├── handlers
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── meta
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── README.md
    ├── tasks
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── templates
    ├── tests
    │   ├── inventory
    │   └── test.yml
    └── vars
        └── main.yml
```

Dependencies, are added to `meta/main.yml`. Assuming, role1 has dependencies marked in this file like (and likewise for role2):

```
dependencies: 
  - role: role2
  - role: role3
```

And, I also have a `requirements.yml` file which looks like:

```
---    
- src: some git link1
  version: master
  name: role2
- src: some git link2
  version: master
  name: role3
```

My question: 
where do I place this `requirements.yml` file for role1?

I understand the requirements will need to be installed by the command,

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml -p roles/
```

And, I can do this for role1, but how does this get automated for role2? Do the successive dependencies need to be resolved and installed manually this way, or is there something better?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Technically speaking, you could put your `requirements.yml` file anywhere you like as long as you reflect the correct path in your `ansible-galaxy install` command.

Meanwhile, if you ever want to run your playbooks from Ansible Tower/Awx, I suggest you stick to the [Ansible Tower requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/projects.html#ansible-galaxy-support) and put your `requirements.yml` file in `<project-top-level-directory>/roles/requirements.yml`

Regarding dependencies between roles, `ansible-galaxy` is able to follow them by itself when they are encountered during installation. So you don't need to specify all of them in your `requirements.yml`, only top level ones. You just need to specify your dependencies correctly in each external roles.

## In `meta/main.yml` for role1

```yaml
dependencies:
  - src: https://my.scm.com/my-ansible-roles/role2.git
    scm: git
    version: master
    name: role2
  - src: https://my.scm.com/my-ansible-roles/role3.git
    scm: git
    version: master
    name: role3
```

## In `meta/main.yml` for role2

```yaml
dependencies:
  - src: https://my.scm.com/my-ansible-roles/role4.git
    scm: git
    version: master
    name: role4
  - src: https://my.scm.com/my-ansible-roles/role5.git
    scm: git
    version: master
    name: role5
```

## `roles/requirements.yml`

```yaml
---    
- src: https://my.scm.com/my-ansible-roles/role1.git
  scm: git
  version: master
  name: role1
```

To be as exhaustive as possible, this is what I now usually do on my projects to handle dependencies locally as well as local/project only roles

## Basic project structure

```
ansible-project-dir
└─── roles
|    └─── locally-versioned-role1
|    └─── locally-versioned-role2
|    └─── ...
|    └─── requirements.yml
|    └─── .gitignore
└─── ansible.cfg
└─── playbook1.yml
└─── playbook2.yml
```

## `ansible.cfg`

I force roles search and downloads in the local `roles` directory by setting `roles_path  = roles`, so user can use `ansible-galaxy install` without the `-p` parameter.

## `roles/requirements.yml`

Already discussed above. Just list dependencies to top-level external (i.e. not versioned in the project) as galaxy role name or as git uris. If you need to fully checkout those roles to later make git commits/push on them, you can use `ansible-galaxy install -g -f -r roles/requirements`

## `roles/.gitignore`

```yaml
# Ignore everything in roles dir
/*
# Except:
# the .gitignore file
!.gitignore
# the requirements file
!requirements.yml
# Readme if you have one
!README.md
# and any specific role we want to version locally
!locally-versioned-role*/
```

Comment: If using `roles/requirements.yml` for declaring dependencies to a git repo (`scm: git`), how does AWX/Tower handle authentication to the git repository? Is there a way to specify it?

Comment: @trebor I'm running a fairly old version of AWX so they might have fixed this issue (not enough time to check right now). But on my version (3.0.0.0, please don't laugh...), I can provide only one key or user/pass scm identification credential in the project form. So you can access private git repos for your project and your roles but they should all share the same credential (e.g. deploy key). This is my case and it works (project and private roles from git scm).