# Integrate Ansible Role

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

My org has a monolithic ansible repository that we manually run from an engineer's machine.  We do not have an ansible server.

I want to re-use an [ansible role](https://github.com/lean-delivery/ansible-role-java#some-examples-of-the-installing-current-role) that can be installed using galaxy.  However, since we don't have an ansible server, I need to integrate this role into our versioned repo so that it can be run by anyone on any machine.

Do I just start copying the directory structure of this locally-installed ansible role into the root of our ansible project?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773505/where-to-place-requirements-yml-for-ansible-and-use-it-to-resolve-dependencies/55774721#55774721) dealing with how to write and where to place a roles requirements file. Duplicating the role in your own VCS is the worse solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what sort of repo solution you use, but Ansible Galaxy can be used with private GitHub. For example:

```
- src: "git+ssh://git@github.example.com/org/my-ansible-role.git"
  name: __remote_role
  version: 0.0.1
```

You can change the ssh protocol to https, but might require some git config on your machine.